# encountered a declaration exception javascript error

Tags: javascript

Me dice "encountered a declaration exception"
ReferenceError: caracteres is not defined y me resalta el return de "return caracteres". Que estoy fallando?

Mi código

```
function repetirCaracteres() {
  // Escribi una funcion llamada 'repeatCharacters' en el prototypo del objeto global String
  // que reciba como parametro un string
  // y devuelve un string en donde cada letra se repita una vez.
  // Por ej:
  // 'hola'.repeatCharacters() devuelve "hhoollaa"

  // Tu código aca:
  String.prototype.repeatCharacters = function (string) {
    for (var i = 0; i< this.length; i++) {
      caracteres = this.charAt().repeat(2);
  }
  }
  return caracteres;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

estas colocando mal el return de caracteres. Lo estabas haciendo fuera de la funcion.

```
function repetirCaracteres() {
  // Escribi una funcion llamada 'repeatCharacters' en el prototypo del objeto global String
  // que reciba como parametro un string
  // y devuelve un string en donde cada letra se repita una vez.
  // Por ej:
  // 'hola'.repeatCharacters() devuelve "hhoollaa"

  // Tu código aca:
  String.prototype.repeatCharacters = function () {
    let texto = this;
    let nuevoTexto = '';
    for (var i = 0; i< texto.length; i++) {
      let letra = texto[i];
      nuevoTexto += letra.charAt().repeat(2);
    }
    return nuevoTexto
  }
}
```

```js
String.prototype.repeatCharacters = function () {
  let texto = this;
  let nuevoTexto = '';
  for (var i = 0; i< texto.length; i++) {
    let letra = texto[i];
    nuevoTexto += letra.charAt().repeat(2);
  }
  return nuevoTexto
}

console.log("hola".repeatCharacters())
```

Comment: PERFECTO muchas gracias. me faltaba tambien ir guardando la letra no?